# Product of sums for a boolean function

Tags: boolean-logic

F = AB + C'D'

how can i factor out this expression to obtain product of sums ,

i think we have to make up two new terms each with zero

like F = AB + C'D' + AA' + B'B or something of the sort but how to do it exactly
any idea appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
F = AB + C'D'
  = (A' + B')' + (C + D)'     ; De Morgan on each term
  = ((A' + B')(C + D))'       ; De Morgan again
```

Answer (score 2):

here is a hint :

Morgans law

AB= ( A' + B' )'

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example

F = ab' + ad + c'd + d'

F'= (ab' + ad + c'd + d')' = (ab')' . (ad)' . (c'd)' . (d')' ---> a'.b' =(a'+b') De Morgans law = (a'+b)(a'+b')(c+d')(d)
Hence Product of sums.

Your case:
F = ab +c'd' = (a'+b')' + (c+d)' = (a'+b').(c+d)

Just use De Morgans law ;)